# Multiple commands with quotations after SSHing

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, quoting

I have a server I have to ssh into with many commands which feature the use of variable assignment and consequently a lot of quotation marks. If we consider the script:

```
ssh user@host  "kinit -k -t /path/to/dir/`whoami`.`hostname -s`.keytab `whoami`/`hostname -f`@host ;

set -x

touch health_check.log ;

echo \"Starting HDFS health check\" > health_check.log ;
echo \"/path/to\" >> health_check.log ;

hdfs dfs -du -h /path/to &>> health_check.log ;

echo \"**************************************************************************
/path/to/dir\" >> health_check.log ;

hdfs dfs -du -h /path/to/dir &>> health_check.log ;

subject=\"HDFS Health Check\" ;
from=\"noreply@example.com\" ;
recipients=\"user@email.com\" ;
mail=\"subject:$subject\nfrom:$from\nContent-Type: text/html\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n\n$(cat health_check.log)\" ;



echo -e $mail | sendmail \"$recipients\" ;

set +x
rm health_check.log
"
```

When I run the script I get this debug output:

```
++ subject='HDFS Health Check'
++ from=noreply@example.com
++ recipients=user@email.com
++ mail='subject:\nfrom:\nContent-Type: text/html\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n\nStarting HDFS health check /data/gftocon'
++ echo -e
++ sendmail ''
```

Notice the empty strings where my variables should be. Why has escaping the quotation marks not worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the script is double quoted: **your shell** is substituting the variables **before** launching the ssh command. You could add some extra backslashes, or use a [quoted heredoc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) like this:

```
ssh user@host  <<'END_COMMANDS'
# ...............^............^ these quotes make the whole document single-quoted
kinit -k -t /path/to/dir/`whoami`.`hostname -s`.keytab `whoami`/`hostname -f`@host
set -x
echo "Starting HDFS health check" > health_check.log 
echo "/path/to" >> health_check.log 
hdfs dfs -du -h /path/to &>> health_check.log 
echo "**************************************************************************
/path/to/dir" >> health_check.log 
hdfs dfs -du -h /path/to/dir &>> health_check.log 

subject="HDFS Health Check" 
from="noreply@example.com" 
recipients="user@email.com" 

headers="subject:$subject
from:$from
Content-Type: text/html
MIME-Version: 1.0"

{ echo "$headers"; echo; cat health_check.log; } | sendmail "$recipients" 

set +x
rm health_check.log
END_COMMANDS
```

I think that's easier to maintain.

Comment: Why are you using "text/html" when the content does not contain html?

Comment: I wanted to see if it would make any change to the format of the email. Unsurprisingly it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should escape the `$` characters from within your `"` `"` block.

Your mail command would become:

```
mail=\"subject:\$subject\nfrom:\$from\nContent-Type: text/html\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n\n\$(cat health_check.log)\"
```

Note: it looks like the `$(cat)` works though. Not sure why.